# How to set individual fields in a MongoDB to expire after a certain amount of time using TTL, rather than the entire document?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I would like some help/advice for the following issue I am having. I have written a program that reads through tweets and awards a user a point if there is a matching keyword in the tweet. I then store the tweet ID's in a database so that the user cannot "cheat" and redeem the same tweet for another point. The database currently looks like this.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd15b68b6a8dfb7b1177dbe"
    },
    "handle": "twitterhandle",
    "member_id": "0000000",
    "points": 3,
    "tweets": [
        "tweet1",
        "tweet2",
        "tweet3"
    ]
}
```

Every 24 hours, I would like to make the tweets field reset back to None - however, I cannot seem to find a way to do this with TTL - it seems that the only option is to delete all of the fields, not just the ones i want. Is there a way to do this w/ pymongo?

Comment: Could you not separate the tweets from the main oid body? And refer to those tweets as a reference. Meaning you can delete the main tweet record via TTL and the reference will be empty, but it would enable the main person entry to remain.

Comment: @Torxed I'm not quite sure what you mean by "enable the main person entry to remain". If I were able to separate the tweets field from the OID, how exactly would I do that/what would it look like? and when i deleted it with TTL, would I still be able to add to the field after it cleared? I'm super new to pyMongo/mongo in general.

Comment: If this is your database and not something that's automatically created. Id would simply create two separate OID's, one for the person object and one for the persons tweets. That way, you can delete the OID belonging to the tweets without affecting the person object. And reference the tweets OID to the person OID. If you don't know what I'm talking about you should go read up on relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do something like this :

```
TweetSchema :
 {
    "tweet": onlyOneTweet
    "handle": "twitterhandle",
    "member_id": "0000000",
    "points": 3,
     "createdAt":{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
        expires: (60*60*24) // 1 day
    },
```

Expires will automatically remove all document created 24 hours before.
And you can retrieve all tweets from one user as you have the memberId reference.
I am not sure you can use TTL for SubDocument, as the function is for removing a document.